# Parse on Android - How to stop receiving push notifications

Tags: android, parsing, notifications, push-notification, push

I configured parse and everything works pretty good; when I send a notification from my server, my phone receives it.

The problem is that when a user unchecks the `checkBox`, he/she should stop receiving notifications.

Here's my code to start Parse service:

```
Parse.initialize(this, "cod1", "cod2");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I already tried stopping notifications with

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().deleteInBackground();
```

and

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("");
```

but none of the two above works :S
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hei. Did you manage to figure this out? I'm facing the same issue ...

Comment: did you manage to solve it?